# Getting errors while capturing images through the Camera in only oppo and realme devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Getting errors while capturing images through the Camera

> java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference

in only oppo and realme devices

```
 Failure delivering result
 ResultInfo{who=null, request=1569638292, result=-1, data=null} to activity
 java.lang.NullPointerException: 
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String 
 java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference

Capture image 



 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

  

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "TEST");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        imageFileName = "JPEG_" + ts + ".jpg";

        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + imageFileName);


    } else {
        return null;
    }


    return mediaFile;
}
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


  final String outputFilePath = mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

}

Comment: There is no call to getAbsolutePath(). Please post the relevant code.

Comment: this is the code

Comment: Then you should tell us which statement exactly causes this error. ??? You added that line? Your first statement now is on the wrong place i think. Its a mess now. Using mediaFile before its defined later.

Comment: final String outputFilePath = utilities.compressImage(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath(), mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Again: you should call that line only later after mediaFile defined.

Comment: getOutputMediaFile() can return null. You are not checking for that.

Comment: You should have `if mediaFile==null) return;` before String outputFilePath = mediaFile.getAbsolutePath()); The message clearly states that getAbsolutePath() is called on a null pointer.