# Android camera issue

Tags: android

I'm having camera  issue.  But my app getting crashed while user taking picture on camera on specific mobiles like Redmi Note 7 pro. Can anyone please help me out of this issue. I'm checking about this issue from last 2 days. I couldn't find any solution for this.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace in your logs?

Comment: Please provide stacktrace

Comment: Same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73246413/camera-capture-image-java-io-file-getabsolutepath-on-a-null-object-reference  and not willing to ask a question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put this permission in manifest ?
It may solve the problem.

```
<uses-permission android:name ="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```